# Different color for different parts of MATLAB title

Tags: matlab, colors, title, figure

I have, what I think might be a 'simple' problem. I know how to change the color of a MATLAB title. What I do not know, is how to use two different colors, at two different parts of the title.

For example, lets say the title of a figure said "Hello World". Then, I want the "Hello" to be in black, while the "World" to be in blue.

How to do this? Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [TeX](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/adding-text-annotations-to-graphs.html#f0-28104) markup to do that. Here's an example:

```
title(['Hello {\color{blue}World}']);
```

Answer (score 6):

[image]

```
% Create text
text('Parent',axes1,...
'String','\fontsize{20} \color{black}Hello \color{blue}World',...
'Position',[4 95 0]);
```