# How to make title interpret only part of a title string in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, tex

I'm creating a plot where I want to combine two strings into a title. I want to color the other part of my string. Here is my code (it will explain itself better):

```
title([csv_name ', {\color{blue}Bowel AUC: ' num2str(bowelAUC) ' }'])
```

In the variable `csv_name` I have a filename containing underscore `_` characters and in the variable `bowelAUC` I have a number. I can color only  part of my title string by using the guide in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16468549/different-color-for-different-parts-of-matlab-title), that is using tex, but the problem now is that tex interpreter would also interpret the `csv_name` variable and I don't want this. Here you can see what I get:

[image]

The filename looks like this: `ExportedPressure_130A_10-29-2014.csv`

So I want `title` to interpret only the second part of my title, not the first...how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to replace `_` by `\_` so that TeX interprets them correctly. To do that you can use [`regexprep`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexprep.html) (note that within `regexprep` both characters are escaped again):

```
csv_name_escaped = regexprep(csv_name, '\_', '\\\_');
title([csv_name_escaped ', {\color{blue}Bowel AUC: ' num2str(bowelAUC) ' }'])
```

Comment: Thank you @LuisMendo, it worked, but I think you forgot the 'none' into your answer? Because it didn't work If I added the 'none' in the command. It worked without the 'none'.